# Modify Info.plist to set "Application is agent(UIElement)" at runtime

Tags: cocoa

Let's say I need to give the user the ability to choose by a preferences panel whether to use the app as "standard" (with dock icon and menu) or as an agent app (with status bar menu only).

I think I need to programmatically modify the app's "Info.plist" during execution, changing the parameter "Application is agent" to YES/NO.

Is this the right way?

P.S. You can find this behavior in "Sparrow".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should not modify your app's `Info.plist` file (or anything in your app's bundle) at runtime. This is bad practice and will also break your app if it is code signed. This is more important nowadays as all apps on the app store must be code signed.

A better option is to use the Application Services function `TransformProcessType()` to move your app from a background to a foreground app.

First, set the `LSUIElement` key in your app's `Info.plist` to `YES` and then check a user default at launch to determine if your app should be running as an agent or not:

```
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"LaunchAsAgentApp"]) 
    {
        ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess };
        TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
        SetFrontProcess(&psn);
    }
}

@end
```

Make sure you don't forget to add the Application Services framework to your project.

Comment: Plus, changing the `Info.plist` will also fail with insufficient privileges and on read-only volumes (like disk images).